# Why do '?' and '\?' give the same output in C?

Tags: c, escaping

In C, why do these two pieces of code give the same output?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char c='\?';
    printf("%c",c);
}
```

and

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char c='?';
    printf("%c",c);
}
```

I understand that a backslash is used to make quotes (`"` or `'`) and a backslash obvious to the compiler when we use printf(), but why does this work for the '?'?

Comment: *"a backslash is used to make quotes"* no, it's used to escape them

Answer (score 86):

`\?` is an escape sequence exactly equivalent to `?`, and is used to escape [*trigraphs*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_alternative#Trigraphs):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("%s %s", "??=", "?\?="); // output is # ??=
}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning: _trigraphs_ are used to write characters that do not exist in a certain character set used to wite C source code. A trigraph conists of `??` plus an alternative character. `??/` for example means \. So to use `??/` in a string literal it must be written as `?\?/` to prevent interpretation as a trigraph.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie -- trigraphs are also used when local keyboards do not have a particular character, even if it's representable in the current character encoding.

Comment: The [characters that can be expressed with trigraphs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Initial-processing.html) are `[` `]` `{` `}` `#` `^` `|` `~` and backslash.  The original rationale for the feature was to make C more practically usable in the [national variants of ISO 646](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646#Variant_comparison_chart) that replaced these characters with additional accented alphabetics.

Comment: @zwol - oh!  I thought it was for programmers condemmed to hell and forced to use EBCDIC for eternity.

Comment: @davidbak There's a _similar_ headache with the many variants of EBCDIC, yes, but it was the ISO 646 variants that the committee had in mind.

Comment: Funny that while C++17 removed trigraphs completely, `\?` is still allowed. :)

Comment: @Rakete1111, seems like an appropriate backward compatibility measure to me. While few used the trigraphs (leading to them being removed), maybe many were forced to use the escape mechanism. Removing the escape would break all code which used to escape the trigraphs before.

Answer (score 29):

Quoting `C11`, chapter [§6.4.4.4p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p4)

> The double-quote `"` and question-mark `?` are representable **either by themselves** or by the escape sequences `\"` and **`\?`**, respectively, but `...` .

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

So the escape sequence `\?` is treated the same as `?`.

Answer (score 20):

Because `'\?'` is a valid [escape code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape), and is equal to a question-mark.

Answer (score 0):

when you're defining a `char` or `string` the compiler parses backslash in that `char` or `string` as an escape sequence.

Answer (score -1):

**

```
the simple answer of your question is 
\? means ?. instead of using \? you can using ? .
\? is escape representation and ? is character representation means both are same.
```

i have linked a image so that you understand it more easily..

**

["click here to see the image " --> in this image you need to find \? in Escape character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHbGn.png)